# Storing multiple users calendars in MySQL table

Tags: java, android, mysql, calendar, timetable

I am currently trying to create an Android app, for my A-Level Computing Practical Project, which stores a users calendar/timetable within a MySQL database and can be accessed by logging into the app. I want to be able to make it so that you can access the calendar from any device as long as you are logged in so I was just wondering what the best way to do this would be as the ways in which I have thought of so far will end up using large amounts of space over time and I wish to prevent this.

Currently I am thinking about creating a table which stores all of the users calendars by their e-mail address, I will then have a field which contains an array of all of the events. I know that this is very inefficient and was wondering if anyone could give me any ideas into how I could do this I would be extremely grateful.

I am also willing to change the method of doing this as I am not stuck with using MySQL

Answer (score 2):

Since you said that you are not stuck with MySQL, why don't you go for any NoSQL DB. 
Data representation in many NoSQL DBs is similar to a JSON.
Your data will look like

```
{
 "email" : "test@example.com",
 "events" : [event1, event2 ....]
}
```

event1 and event2 themselves can be JSON objects,

```
{
 "email" : "test@example.com",
 "events" : [
              {
                "name" : "a1",
                "type" : "t1",
                "time" : "date1"
               },
              {
                "name" : "a2",
                "type" : "t2",
                "time" : "date2"
               }
            ]
}
```

Many of them support querying these objects based on params. There are lot many NoSQL DBs out there. I would personally suggest to go for MongoDB (https://www.mongodb.org/about/) . It is simple and has a good documentation.

Answer (score 1):

My MySQL schema for this problem would be like this

```
User: id int, email str, very_securely_hashed_password str
Event: id int, user_id integer, title str, description str, time str
```

or something like that. I'm assuming you have some way of authenticating the users; maybe it's not in your db. Either way, I don't think it's a problem to look up by the user's ID or the email as a foreign key, but using user_id is more classic.

Then you can do

```
SELECT * FROM Event WHERE user_id = 4;
```

and it returns one row for every event, rather than you needing to parse a huge string.